# Does assignment with an array element copy or reference the element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not sure of the terminology to search for an answer to this. Given:

```
this.snake = [{x: 0, y: 0}];
var curhead = this.snake[0];
```

Does `curhead` contain a copy of the dictionary(?) at `snake[0]` or a direct reference to it?

Comment: `curhead` will have a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript always copies by value.

Objects in JavaScript, including Arrays, are only ever accessed by reference though. (i.e. `foo = []` generates an array and assigns a reference to it to `foo`).

So you will get a copy of the first value in the array, which is a reference to the object.

---

This is distinct from being a reference to the first value in the array.

Given:

```
var array = [ { value: 1 } ];
var reference = array[0];
array.unshift( { value: 2 } );
```

If `reference` was a reference to the first value in the array, then by changing the first value it would point to the object with `value : 2`.

Since it is a copy of the value, it continues to be a reference to the object with `value : 1` (which is now the second value in the array).

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given, `curhead` will contain a *reference* to the first item in the array `snake`

Comment: me too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of objects with only one element. So

```
this.snake[0]
```

Will contain a reference to  {x: 0, y: 0}.

Paras

Answer (score -1):

Now `curHead` and `snake[0]` refers to the exact same memory location . Try changing a value in `curHead` it will change `snake[0]` as well

```
curhead.x = 1
console.log(curhead)
//Object {x: 1, y: 0}
console.log(this.snake)
//[{x: 1, y: 0}]
```

Fun things happen when you try to assign a completely new object to `curhead` , lets say `curhead = 'hi'` . Then javaScript will create a new heap space for `curhead` and `this.snake` will be unchanged to its value `{x: 1, y: 0}`

Comment: "to the exact same memory location" — That's an implementation detail.

Comment: @sam if the answer was helpful please accept it by clicking check mark next to upvote section.